# Why Soul Bound Tokens (SBT) are Non Transferable?

Tags: nft, identity

I'm aware that Soul Bound Tokens (SBT) are Non Transferable to ensure that certain attributes are linked to a wallet address.

That makes sense, but comes with lots of limitations. I have multiple wallet addresses, and I can imagine many scenarios where I would like to transfer my SBT identity  to a different wallet address.

Make SBT transferable would also help to improve privacy.

Could anyone give me good reasons to keep a non transferable approach in SBTs?

Thanks

Comment: It the tokens are transferable to another wallet, they become "unbound" and defeat the purpose of "soulboundedness".  For example to provide "membership access" on the account owners IRL identity.  If that token can be transferred to another wallet (which then becomes "ownerOf" the token) that's precisely contrary to the token's purpose.  Many use cases for this kind of token, as an "access key" member resources, as a signifier in membership in a group or club, etc., none of which is designed to be directly transferable from the member to some other anonymous account owner.

Comment: But what I mean is, that if the token MUST be bounded to one address... It would be even more efficient to keep track of the "authorized/owner" wallet addresses in a contract, rather than sending them an NFT.

Comment: Answering to your proposed use case, I would say that if one of the advantadges of tokenization is liquidity (secondary markets), I should be able to transfer or sell my membership NFT. Why make it non transferable?

Comment: Well, ultimately its not up to the token owner, but rather up to the contract's author if a token is meant to be transferrable.   There are plenty of 'memberships' that are not designed to be transferrable,  For example if you are voting member of the AMPAS, you get to vote on who gets an Oscar, possibly because you won one.  Those membership are not transferrable according to the rules, and it's positive that the blockchain can model such a "non-transferrable membership token" for use cases like these.  Liquidity really isn't the issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A good reason to keep a non-transferrable approach in SBT is that it's designed specifically to to represent part of a person’s identity in a decentralized digital world. This type of soul-bounded token is meant to be used as credentials in every day life, as the risk of mismanaging digital identity can be disastrous in businesses as the result of the rise in offering services, conducting transactions, and moving data on the Web.

This approach may have lots of limitations, and you can imagine many scenarios where you would like to transfer your SBT identity to a different wallet address, but this is entirely a personal choice. Nevertheless, in the business world, authorities are more concerned with the risks, as risk management is paramount to the success in business before one reaps the benefits.